# Detect Android orientation: landscape-Left v. landscape-Right

Tags: android

How can I detect which one of 4 sides of the phone is up.

I can detect portrait/landscape mode, but how do I tell **landscape-turned-on-left-side** from **landscape-turned-on-right-side**?

Basically I want to make a nice transition animation when user turns phone. You know, like in iPhone's Safari: a swift 400ms rotation from the previous layout to the new.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an OrientationEventListener:

```
mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) 
{ 
 @Override
 public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) 
 {
  mDeviceOrientation = orientation;
 }
};

if(mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation())
{
 mOrientationEventListener.enable();
}
```

mDeviceOrientation should then be an integer telling you the angle your device is rotated to, if you do some clever rounding you should be able to see which of the four orientations it is in:

```
// Divide by 90 into an int to round, then multiply out to one of 5 positions, either 0,90,180,270,360. 
int orientation = 90*Math.round(mDeviceOrientation / 90); 

// Convert 360 to 0
if(orientation == 360)
{
    orientation = 0;
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Your rounding code is wrong. You want: (90*Math.round(mDeviceOrientation/90))%360;
Other than that you'll probably want to handle the case where ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN is returned, see the docs.

Comment: But a bit off apparently, perhaps because of that SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL. Rendering for the view is invoked before onOrientationChanged, so at the point where I need to render there's no info on orientation change yet.

Comment: @pheelicks ah yes, oops forgot to actually multiply it after i'd divided it... I've updated the code in the post now.

Comment: Yesss!! Got it working now with some voodoo. I wish Google were slightly more sensible to not require hacking for such a trivial task.

Comment: I've just noticed this, don't know if it works...  
 
Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
display.getRotation(); 

 
its api level 8+ only though :/

Comment: Keep in mind that the orientation value returned in OnOrientationChanged is respective to the device's natural position and there are some devices which have landscape as its natural position.  See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Comment: Just implementing this myself, and the dissection into quarters isn't as straightforward as this reply. I have 0 degrees straight down and rotation measured anticlockwise around the screen. Thus Portrait is between 305>0<45 degrees, needing a little maths to solve or fry15's discovery. @NeTelStEiN - if you get the Orientation feedback and measure Landscape against degrees, you can work it out. However, my experience with my handset suggests this whole method is unreliable.

Answer (score 9):

Just came across :) 2.2+ put xml code to ur res/values(false) and res/values-xlarge(true)

```
<resources>
<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
```

```
private void getScreenRotationOnPhone() {

    final Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    switch (display.getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
            break;
    }
}

private void getScreenRotationOnTablet() {

    final Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    switch (display.getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
            break;
    }
}

private boolean isTabletDevice(){
    boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (tabletSize) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code will not work on devices which have "natural position" set to landscape (such as certain tablets). If anyone has any idea how to find "natural position" of a device please share. It's really a shame there is no API to do it in Android.

Comment: That's true. I edited the code to version for tablet as well. Thx mate! Hope they are going to release API for that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should be able to tell from the [screenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation), gotten via [getRequestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getRequestedOrientation%28%29)

Comment: No, that's no good, it only returns landscape or portrait. What I need is **which** landscape is it. When you turn phone on its left side or its right side Android renders UI in two opposite orientations.

Comment: Yes, I assume that the values reverse_landscape and reverse_portrait would tell you that.  Note that these are only available in API level 9.  What version of the SDK are you using?  What device are you testing on?  You can presumably only get this information if you are running 2.3 or higher.

Comment: Actually yes, API9 does mention that 'reverse' part. Such a shame they didn't think of it earlier. I don't think it's reasonable to expect 2.3 at this moment -- almost not devices out there running it yet.

Comment: I'd love to reverse "-1" with that information, but it doesn't let me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get landscape left vs right events using this code:

```
object : OrientationEventListener(this, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
    override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
        afterGlobalLayout {
            logInfoToast(if (screenRotation == LandscapeLeft)
                "LandscapeLeft" else "LandscapeRight")
        }
    }
}.enable()
```

`afterGlobalLayout` uses `viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

and `screenRotation` is calculated by Piotr Ślesarew code.