# Android screenOrientation vs Rotation

Tags: android

I am using OrientationEventListener to correctly orient my activity when user rotates the device. I orient the activity by calling Activity.setRequestedOrientation(int).

My problem is that OrientationEventListener returns angle from "natural device position". setRequestedOrientation takes argument such as SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT etc. To translate from angle to orientation I need to know what "natural device position" is, i.e. is it landscape left, landscape right, portrait or portrait reversed. Unfortunately the API doesn't seem to have a way to find out.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

I think you can use onConfigurationChanged to get called whenever Orientation is changed.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not to figure out current orientation (that is easy enough) but to translate from angle to orientation.

Comment: Ahh my bad, then this is what you want I think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727800/detect-android-orientation-landscape-left-v-landscape-right

Comment: Really sorry to say no again, but this deals with how to round the angle value so that it comes in multiplies of 90 degrees, nothing to do with my problem. And the last answer, which partially does, is wrong... I've done the googling already, there isn't anything obvious out there unless I missed it. That's why I asked here.

Comment: I almost want to keep trying so we can keep this back and forth going, but I desist! :-) I fully understand the nature of the question now - good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

From documentation:

`Overall orientation of the screen. May be one of ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.`

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not to figure out current orientation (that is easy enough) but to translate from angle returned by the sensors to absolute orientation